# lightning:combobox change icon

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-combobox

If you notice the lightning:combobox component, you will see that there is an icon pointing downwards on click of which list box opens.

Is there any way to change the icon pointing upwards ONLY when the listbox is open?

[image]

Comment: Looks like the icon generated by Salesforce using the lightning:combobox component is a svg icon. So you can't change it using css. The only way I see would be to create your component from scratch using the lightnign design system

Comment: When I created a custom component, then I am able to do this. But I am trying to do the same using the lightning:combobox component.

Comment: Any ideas? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rotate the icon when the dropdown is open using CSS, like so:

```
.THIS .slds-dropdown-trigger.slds-is-open .slds-combobox__form-element .slds-icon {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Note, that this is not a very elegant solution as it relies on the internal structure of the `lightning:combobox` which can change without notice, but technically it does the trick.